# Android GoogleMaps API v2 auth error, i do not get the error when running on an AVD but on my nexus 7 i get an auth error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am developing an Android application which uses Google maps for android v2. The problem i having is that when i run it using the AVD in Eclipse i recieve no authentication error in the log cat output.

I am now testing my application on an Android tablet (nexus 7 2013) and i recieve this error when executing the application:

```
12-12 01:09:13.968: E/Google Maps Android API(14759): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-12 01:09:13.968: E/Google Maps Android API(14759): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02, API Key: AIzaSyDcnzt6cdjEbCXSCRSTezmUHbaPW679if8, Certificate Fingerprint: 52FDB9ABBBAA062226834E35BF6A39FA2A3E27A7
```

I have tried to regen the API key, the one in the logcat matches the one provided in the google API console.

I have tried a clean project/clean install on the device several times, still no luck. The reast of the application works fine, only the map does not.

Here is my manifest.xml al the permissions seem ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <permission
        android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Accessing camera hardware -->
    <!-- putting android.hardware.camera prevents non-camera devices using this app -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.StartScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.CreateWalkActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_walk" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.HelpScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.WalkRecording"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_walk_recording" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.CreateNewPOIActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create_new_poi" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDcnzt6cdjEbCXSCRSTezmUHbaPW679if8" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.ConfrimUploadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_confrim_upload" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02.ServerResponse"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_server_response" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the xml where the map is located:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".WalkRecording" >

    <fragment

        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/walkRecordingHelpButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/helpIconAltText"
        android:src="@drawable/help" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/walkRecordingNewPOIButton"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/walkRecordingNewPOIButtonText"
        android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/walkRecordingUploadButton"
         style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
         android:layout_width="85dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/walkRecordingNewPOIButton"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/walkRecordingNewPOIButton"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:text="@string/walkRecordingUploadButtonText"
         android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code:

```
package dcs.aber.ac.uk.cs211.group02;

import java.util.Vector;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WalkRecording extends FragmentActivity {

    private static String walkName, walkSDesc, walkLdesc;


    private GoogleMap map;
    private Context context;
    private Button newPOIButton, uploadButton;
    private ImageButton helpButton;
    private static Vector<PointOfInterest> pois = new Vector<PointOfInterest>();

    private CreateNewPOIActivity POIAct;

    private final static int NEW_POI_REQ = 0;
    private final static int EDIT_WALK_DETAILS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walk_recording);
        context = this;

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("Walk info");

        if(bundle != null){

            walkName = bundle.getString("walkTitle");
            walkSDesc = bundle.getString("walkSdesc");
            walkLdesc = bundle.getString("walkLDesc");

        }


        map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();

        map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(52.4140,4.0810) , 14.0f));         

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);




        POIAct = new CreateNewPOIActivity();

        addOnClickListeners();
    }


    public void addOnClickListeners(){

        helpButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.walkRecordingHelpButton);

        helpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, HelpScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

        newPOIButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.walkRecordingNewPOIButton);

        newPOIButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CreateNewPOIActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_POI_REQ);   

            }

        });

        uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.walkRecordingUploadButton);

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfrimUploadActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();


                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.walk_recording, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void uploadTosever() {




    }

    public void deleteWalk() {


    }

    public double getLongitude() {

        return 0;
    }

    public double getLattitude() {

        return 0;

    }


    public static Vector<PointOfInterest> getPois() {
        return pois;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == NEW_POI_REQ){
            if( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
                PointOfInterest p = data.getExtras().getParcelable("POIObject");
                Toast lol = Toast.makeText(context, p.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                lol.show();
                pois.add(p);
                Toast x = Toast.makeText(context, "POIS SIZE " + pois.size() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                x.show();

            }
        }
        else if(requestCode == EDIT_WALK_DETAILS){
            if( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {



            }

        }
    }

    public static String getWalkName() {
        return walkName;
    }


    public static void setWalkName(String walkName) {
        WalkRecording.walkName = walkName;
    }


    public static String getWalkSDesc() {
        return walkSDesc;
    }


    public static void setWalkSDesc(String walkSDesc) {
        WalkRecording.walkSDesc = walkSDesc;
    }


    public static String getWalkLdesc() {
        return walkLdesc;
    }


    public static void setWalkLdesc(String walkLdesc) {
        WalkRecording.walkLdesc = walkLdesc;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. alls it took was a device reset...